# Generate svg.js object for a (SVG) DOM node not created by svg.js

Tags: svg.js

I use svg.js to create an SVG image within a HTML document. However, I want to add a few elements that are not created by svg.js, but rather some other code. I know that there is the `.svg()` method that takes SVG source and adds it, but I have the actual DOM element, which is already part of the SVG. Is there a way to get an svg.js object for this DOM element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are searching for is the `SVG.adopt()` method which takes a node and returns an SVG.js object.

You can also use the `SVG.select()` method which takes a css selector and returns a set of SVG.js elements. Because it's a set (sort of array) you need to get the first element with `SVG.select(something).get(0)`

Comment: I could not find `SVG.adopt()` in `2.3.2`. The docs mention an extension by the name [`absorb`](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.absorb.js) , but that one in turn says it's now included in `svg.js`. `SVG.select()` worked. Thanks!

Comment: `SVG.adopt` is included since `2.0.0` while `absorb` is deprecated (only  useful for svg.js v1.x.x). `adopt` is not mentioned in the docs because the usual way to get elements is with `SVG.select`. However: Especially for use cases when you have a node it fits perfectly